# Is there a way of selecting between variadic template functions based on an enum that is simpler than wrapping the functions in a struct?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Current code is as follows:

```
// header file...
enum class FuncType {
    AddTwoInts,
    SquareAnInt
};

template<FuncType F, typename... Ts>
int getValue(Ts...);

// ----------------------------------------
// cpp file...

template<FuncType F>
struct FuncHelper;

template<>
struct FuncHelper<FuncType::AddTwoInts> {
    static int func(int v1, int v2) {return v1 + v2;}
}

template<>
struct FuncHelper<FuncType::SquareAnInt> {
    static int func(int v) { return v*v; }
}

template <FuncType F, typename... Ts>
int getValue(Ts... args) {
    return FuncHelper<F>::func(args...);
}

// explicitly instantiate versions of getValue for each FuncType
// with the correct args...
template int getValue<FuncType::AddTwoInts, int, int>(int , int);
template int getValue<FuncType::SquareAnInt, int>(int)
```

The above can be used by include the header and then calling like

```
auto val = getValue<FuncType::AddTwoInts>( 3, 4 );
```

This is the exact interface I want but would like to do the implementation without needing to use FuncHelper or something equivalent. Is there a way to select variadic templates at compile time more directly?

Also are there any problems with the above that I am not seeing? My actual use case for the above is as a factory fuction for a struct type that is some data + an std::function.

Comment: Does it matter where you are defining the `func`s? And I assume they are really named the same in your actual code?

Comment: Well this is a toy example. But basically the intention is for the functions names to be hidden in the CPP file with getValue<V> function being the only interface to them. So it doesnt matter what they are names in that the names will be internal

Comment: SO intention is the following: (1) PIMPL like interface to factory functions and (2) -- you cant see this in the toy example because it is so simple -- to share code that will be common across all of the functions i.e. it would be like if there was more code in the body of getValue() above beyond just calling the helper fuinction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with SFINAE, if you just want to avoid the struct.

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class FuncType {
    AddTwoInts,
    MulTwoInts,
    SquareAnInt,
    ReturnAnInt
};

template<FuncType F, typename... Ts>
int getValue(Ts...);

// ----------------------------------------
// cpp file...

template<FuncType F, typename std::enable_if<F == FuncType::AddTwoInts, int>::type D>
int getValue_aux(int v1, int v2) { return v1 + v2; }

template<FuncType F, typename std::enable_if<F == FuncType::MulTwoInts, int>::type D>
int getValue_aux(int v1, int v2) { return v1 * v2; }

template<FuncType F, typename std::enable_if<F == FuncType::SquareAnInt, int>::type D>
int getValue_aux(int v) { return v * v; }

template<FuncType F, typename std::enable_if<F == FuncType::ReturnAnInt, int>::type D>
int getValue_aux(int v) { return v; }

template<FuncType F, typename... Ts>
int getValue(Ts... args)
{
    return getValue_aux<F, 0>(args...);
}
```

It's not possible to have multiple implementations internally without an auxiliary function, simply because they have different arity (so you need somewhere to unpack your variadic args). If all your impls had the same parameter list (or if there were a relatively small number of possible parameter list), you could simply `switch` on the `FuncType` and let the optimizer do the work of selecting the right one at compile time.

Comment: I notice that if I don't do the enable_if with the dummy integer parameter I get an error about the template functions not being distinguishable if the functions have the same signatures. That is if I just do typename = std::enable_if<blah>. But if I do it the way you do above it is fine. Not sure I understand why the above makes them distinguishable?

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, you may do:

```
template<FuncType F, typename... Ts>
int getValue(Ts...args)
{
    if constexpr (F == FuncType::AddTwoInts) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == 2, "!");
        return (args + ...);   
    } else {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == 1, "!");
        const auto& first = std::get<0>(std::tie(args...));
        return first * first;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34f7401524ccb215)